# WPF - Simple timeline in DataGrid

Tags: wpf

i need to realize a simple timeline in a datagrid (72 months).

Today i started with a test (class and xaml below), where i create a property for each month as bool, create a datagridview with 74 columns (Title,Amount and 72 months), and bind each month-column (DataGridTemplateColumn) to the bool value (with da datatrigger to turn it red). Finally it looks ok and works, but i think, there must be a better way to realize it (e.g. don't create a property for each month/don't create a DataGridTemplateColumn for each month)

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Best regards,

Flo

[image: TimeLine]

Class:

```
public class TestItem
{
    public string Ttile { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public bool Month1 { get; set; }
    public bool Month2 { get; set; }

}
```

Xaml:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="TimeLineDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TitleTextColumn" Binding="{Binding Title}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="laufende und geplante&#x0a;Vorhaben" />
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="AmountColumn" Binding="{Binding Amount}" Header="Amount">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Month1}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Month2}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. It's not a great solution, but i've made just one DataGridTemplateColumn with lots of different additional classes and resources. Took a lot of time - not a great solution, but m.b. will be helpful for you, so now it looks as something like that:

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn
        x:Name="MainGanttColumn" Width="SizeToCells">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFB2BECE"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC3D4EB" Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF5FC"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Name="ControlTimeLine" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Margin="0" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Border.Child>
                                        <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},Path=Data.GanttCalendar}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource GanttHeaderStyle}"/>
                                    </Border.Child>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ItemsControl Panel.ZIndex="3" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding GanttTasks}" Name="Lines">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <local:GanttElementsPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},Path=Data.GanttCalendar}" MinDate="{Binding MinDate}" MaxDate="{Binding MaxDate}" GanttVariant="{Binding GanttVariant}" DayWidth="{StaticResource GridLineDayWidth}" MonthWidth="{StaticResource GridLineMonthWidth}" YearWidth="{StaticResource GridLineYearWidth}"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="local:GanttElementsPanel.StartDate" Value="{Binding Path=Start}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="local:GanttElementsPanel.EndDate" Value="{Binding Path=End}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GanttGridLinesTemplate}" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},Path=Data.GridLines}" Height="{Binding ElementName=Lines.ActualHeight}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THLqD.png)